# SQL retrieves duplicate even if distinct specified

Tags: sql

Im trying to retrieve some distinct `competence_id` rows from a table that has duplicate ones based on:

```
select distinct competences.competence_id, skillmgt.* 
from competences
join skillmgt 
on competences.competence_id=skillmgt.cid
Where skillmgt.eid=121 and datename(yyyy,skillmgt.timestamp)='2013'
```

but it gets all the `competence_id`s with their duplicates.

Comment: Please put up sql fiddle

Comment: `DISTINCT` will have effect on the whole row, not just `competence_id`, so if the values in `skillmgt.*` differ, you'll get more rows.

Comment: So how can i bond it to only competence_id?

Comment: Sure, you can get a single row per `competence_id`, but if there are several matching rows in `skillmgt`, which of them would you want in the single resulting row?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Actually the distinct column is in the skillmgt table. I need to get the corresponding fields to that column from the other table ( competences)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do group by.

```
select competences.competence_id, skillmgt.* 
from competences
join skillmgt 
on competences.competence_id=skillmgt.cid
group by competences.competence_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine this would work (I'm guessing with some of your column names):

```
select competences.competence_id, skillmgt.* 
from competences c
join skillmgt s
on c.competence_id=s.cid
where s.sid = (select max(sqs.sid) from skillmgt sqs where c.competence_id=sqs.cid)
```

You don't say which versions of SQL you're using. If I was doing this with SQL Server 2005 and later then I'd use the ROW_NUMBER function which is slightly more elegant.

Comment: This works fine but when I add a an extra condition to the where:
`datename(yyyy,s.timestamp)='2013'` it does not show all the results..

Comment: @auiscs you'd have to add the same `WHERE` clause to the subquery and the outer query.